# MSMQ for those application which are deployed on different machines

Tags: c#, msmq

I am wondering how can i use msmq with different application which are deployed on different machine. MSMQ will work perfectly for those application which are deployed on the same server.

Server 1

Webapplicaiton 1

Webapplication 2

Both appplication can exchange message using msmq.

MSMQ can be help full if the application are deployed on different machines?

Server 1

Application 1

Server 2

Application 2

How they will exchange messages as both are deployed on separate servers.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is your observation? Did you try that out?

Comment: i have an idea i have to deploy the web services which have the rights to access the queue, and rest of the world will access that web api. ?

Comment: http://nthrbldyblg.blogspot.sg/2017/02/msmq-between-two-computers.html

Answer (score 0):

You can send messages across servers using MSMQ. I don't know your how your websites interact but this might help.

Look at the following article regarding [Direct Format Names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700996(v=vs.85).aspx)